# Which linux distributions primarily target KDE?

Tags: linux, kde

I've been playing with Kubuntu, but it seems to lack the polish of Ubuntu.

I am looking for a linux distro in which KDE is the first-class desktop environment.  Which linux distributions primarily target KDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to the question of which of the distributions support KDE, all of them do (this is, after all, Linux!). Even redhat comes with a KDE version.

However, the bigger question of which ones create a beautiful polished version using KDE, the answer is none. At least, not on the level that Ubuntu has gone to with Gnome in the latest incarnation of the OS.

I too have been disappointed with Kubuntu as I use a laptop with ubuntu, and the lack of xsplash, integration features, "whole package" that you get with kubuntu is annoying.

OpenSuse is your best bet for the best looking, best integrated, but it's not as polished as ubuntu. The general annoyance of moving to RPMs from debian has put me off, that and the huge amount of customisation I've done to my kubuntu to make it work as I want.

Answer (score 7):

[OpenSUSE](http://en.opensuse.org/Welcome_to_openSUSE.org) is very KDE-centric.

Comment: Now they are, before they cared for neither over the other. 
Why KDE? 
because it is the more polished desktop, better looking, more programs and themes, and generally easier to use. The gnome menu, blows for one.

Answer (score 5):

See the list [here](http://www.kde.org/download/distributions.php) for which distros come with KDE.

Out of this list, the ones I am aware of that have KDE by default are [Mandriva](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mandriva), [PCLinuxOS](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=pclinuxos), [OpenSUSE](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=suse) and [Knoppix](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=pclinuxos).  Note that there are probably more on that list that do so, but these are the only ones I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

http://chakra-project.org/ - "project created by a bunch of people who like Arch Linux and the K Desktop Environment."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still the case, but Mandriva (formerly Mandrake) used to come with KDE configured as the default window manager.

Answer (score 0):

[Mepis](https://www.mepis.org/) uses KDE.

I have one computer running Kubuntu 8.04 and one running Mepis, and I'm thinking Mepis (using KDE 3.5) is nicer.

I don't like KDE4

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe nobody has mentioned [Slackware](http://www.slackware.com/) yet! It's the oldest distribution still being maintained and it has had a big part in KDE's popularity.

Comment: Switching from the guts of Ubuntu to the guts of Slackware might be painful :-)

Answer (score 0):

This post from TuxRadar, entitled [Get the best KDE Linux distro](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/get-best-kde-linux-distro), has a good group review of 8 KDE-based distributions.  OpenSUSE is their overall winner.